# How can i create ArrayList with Type parameter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Im trying to make universal class and function for different data model classes. My question is how to create ArrayList by Type parameter, type represents each time different class e.g Employee, Warehouse etc.

```
fun foo(type: Type){
    var myList = ArrayList<type>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin has generics, which can be used in the following way:

```
fun <T> foo() {
    val myList = ArrayList<T>()
}
```

It is important to note that you have to know the type of `T` at compile time. Otherwise you should probably look at reflection.